# Can install snaps only from terminal, graphical store says "invalid credentials"

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, snap

I am on Ubuntu 16.04 installation. Snap applications work OK if I install them from terminal, they are auto-updating etc.

But when I try to install any snap from graphical tool, I got:

```
snapd operation finished with error cannot perform the following tasks:
- Download snap "VLC" (770) from channel "stable" (invalid credentials)
```

Will be grateful for any tips on how to repair graphical store (Ubuntu-software)

Comment: after upgrading to 18.04, problem remains the same